# Struggling with the usage of List and ArrayList

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I am trying the following codes to suffle the elements of an `ArrayList`- `questionsAndSeperators`. I am doing this with two ways.
**Method 1:-**

```
List<Question> questionList = this.questionsAndSeperators.Cast<Question>().ToList();

Random rng = new Random();
int questionCount = questionList.Count;
while (questionCount > 1)
{
   questionCount--;
   int index = rng.Next(questionCount + 1);
   Question value = questionList[index];
   questionList[index] = questionList[questionCount];
   questionList[questionCount] = value;
}
```

**Method 2:-**

```
ArrayList questionList = this.questionsAndSeperators;

Random rng = new Random();
int questionCount = questionList.Count;
while (questionCount > 1)
{
   questionCount--;
   int index = rng.Next(questionCount + 1);
   object value = questionList[index];
   questionList[index] = questionList[questionCount];
   questionList[questionCount] = value;
}
```

Here `Question` is a class.
**Method 2** is working fine and suffling the elements of `questionsAndSeperators`, but **Method 1** is not able to suffle the elements of `questionsAndSeperators`. What is the problem with **Method 1**?? 
Am I doing something wrong in method 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Method 1 you create a `new List<Question>` with all elements of `this.questionsAndSeperators`.
Then you shuffle all elements of the `new List<Question>`. But you don't shuffle the elements of `this.questionsAndSeperators` because its another array.

In Method 2 you access the `ArrayList` directly and you shuffle the elements of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: no no, in method 2 I am suffling the elements of `questionList` and `questionandseparators` are suffling!

Comment: in method 2 `questionList` and `questionandseparators` are the same object, and method 1 they are not the same

Comment: @Jaguar That is what he is saying; by saying `questionList = this.questionsAndSeperators` you are making them refer to the same `object`, in the previous method the elements are copied into a new `object`, so shuffling only happens in the new `object`.

Answer (score 0):

In version one you are assign to a variable called "list", but then you are doing the shuffling in a variable called "questionList". I'm wondering that this compiles.

Comment: sorry, by mistake I written `list`. it was `questionList` in method1. Editted